# defer jquery file creates bad visual effects: is it a good practice?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am useing defer attribute to load jquery:

```
<script defer src="{{ asset('js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js') }}"></script>
```

I read that `defer` a js file is the best new practice to include a js file.

The problem occurs when I use jquery to add / remove css classes to a DOM element, or for example when I use select2.
For example with this code:

```
var dayHeader = '';
jQuery('.title_day').each(function( index ) {
    if (jQuery(this).html() == dayHeader) {
        jQuery(this).addClass('notitle');
    }

    dayHeader = jQuery(this).html();
});
```

In these cases the user sees the page without new classes (or without select2), and the result is a bad visual effect (you see an element with a style, and after the deferred js file is loaded the same element changes its style).

How can I solve it? Just do not use `defer` with jquery?

Comment: Under normal circumstance it is good practice to use `defer` in order to loade the page faster, however if the inital layout of the page will be affected after the defered file is loaded then maybe you can make an exception and not use defer.

Comment: Alternatively, looking at what the above code does, perhaps you could also apply the css server-side rather than in client-side.

Comment: @Qiniso thanks, I will try both of your answers